# transitionend firing +1 event with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have an `if` statement that checks if an element has a `style` `attr`. If the `style` attribute is not present it adds some inline styling. If it is present it removes it. I use a transition with the styling that gets added.

I'd like to do `//something` after the `transition` ends via `transitionend`, but the issue I am facing is that every subsequent click to the element produces another `transitionend` event.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7wbzLv7/2/) that depicts this behavior.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unbind before you set it

```js
$('.box').unbind(transEnd);
```

this cuts down on the alerts greatly

before: more and more are shown

after: only 3-4 are shown each time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is every button click is adding a new transitionEnd event handler, you can use a single handler outside of the click handler

```
$('button').on('click', function () {

    var inStyle = $('.box').attr('style')

    if (typeof inStyle !== typeof undefined && inStyle !== false) {
        $('.box').removeAttr("style");
    } else {
        $('.box').css('border-color', 'blue');
    }

});
var transEnd = 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd'
$('.box').on(transEnd, function (e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.originalEvent.propertyName, e)
});
```

---

Another option is to use [.one()](https://api.jquery.com/one) to register a handler which will be triggered only once like

```
$('button').on('click', function () {

    var inStyle = $('.box').attr('style')
    var transEnd = 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd'

    if (typeof inStyle !== typeof undefined && inStyle !== false) {
        $('.box').removeAttr("style");
    } else {
        $('.box').css('border-color', 'blue');
    }

    $('.box').one(transEnd, function (e) {
        alert('transition ended');
    });

});
```